# Spring Boot Oauth2 UserDetailsService from database - access denied

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I've been trying to implement Oauth2 authorisation and resource servers. Up until now I've just been using a hard coded user:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        UserDetails user=User.builder()
            .username("user")
            .password( passwordEncoder().encode("secret") )
            .roles("USER")
            .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
```

This has worked out well. But I have multiple users in my database that I want to use as users login instead.

So, I've removed the above @Bean method from that class and implemented UserDetailsService as a class of its own:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        System.out.println("loadUserByUsername: "+user);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
    }
}
```

And my UserDetails implementation:

```
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1480402973442569981L;
    private User user;

    public MyUserPrincipal(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        System.out.println("Getting username: "+user.getUsername());
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        System.out.println("Getting password: "+user.getPassword());
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

}
```

I've the following in my user table:

```
mysql> select * from user;
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| id | password                                                     | username |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|  1 | $2a$10$7tYTQ/dMXASLZG2OptweV.JdVH9RoDsG2ighxq5im3A/srnOo9OYC | user     |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

With this new setup, I am able to retrieve my access token as before:

POST /oauth/token

```
{
    "access_token": "8cf0a509-2a56-4adc-ace7-38f39beee8a1",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "742a109f-6768-48b5-9818-76397dc658fb",
    "expires_in": 42705,
    "scope": "read write"
}
```

However, when I try to access the resource as before it now gives me the following response:

GET /funds

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "Access is denied"
}
```

I'm not seeing any errors or exceptions thrown. I suspected it was something to do with the roles and this user just not being authorized. Here is my ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer setup:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    //...

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("cliente")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT", "USER")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .autoApprove(true)
            .secret(passwordEncoder().encode("password"));

    }
```

UPDATE

Here's my ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.anonymous().disable()
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/funds/**")
            .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/funds/**")
                .access("hasRole('USER')")
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security automatically prefixes any role with `ROLE_`. The changes were made as part of [SEC-2758](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2984)

Since SimpleGrantedAuthority is an authority, not a role we need to explicitly add the `ROLE_` prefix to make it role.

Following code needs to be updated with `ROLE_` prefix:

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    return authorities;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer setup you need to provide user role as "ROLE_USER" and not "USER".
Because internally (in User) all roles are saved with prefix **ROLE_**.

In user class (the suffix is added):

```
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment. Actually, I'm seeing inconsistant results. Sometimes it works, and then with on the next request I'm seeing access_denied. I'm wondering if it's to do with my resource server. I've updated my post to include my ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter implementation if that helps.